# Unity 2D game Shooting Target Problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

so basically i have a target like the type for archery the 3 rings (bullseye, inner circle and outer circle)

now i basically used a cylinder to create these and then added to them rigidbody2D and a circleCollider 2D , now my problem is because the rings are essentially on top of each other i have them layered out on the z axis a little to make them all visible but when it comes to doing a raycast2d on the target it isnt picking correct ones up for example it goes from outer circle straight to bullseye and skips out inner circle yet all have colliders set up the same way

i cant figure out a way to overcome this and if not ill have to change to a different target where nothing overlaps in order to get it to work but i would really like the archery type targets

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just vary the distance from the camera for each ring so that the ones over the top are hit first.

Alternatively you could add tags to the three rings, use raycast all, and check the tags of all hit colliders to decide which one was hit first. For example, if all 3 register a hit, then you know the center was hit, and if the outer 2 register then you know it's the inner ring, and so on.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html

[image: stacked quads]

Comment: ahhh thank you :) you see i feel silly asking but now i learnt a new command and will abuse the hell out of it :D thanks